# How to split a string at the last occurence of a sequence

Tags: swift, string, split

Target: A string with a built-in separator shall be split in an int and another string. In the case that the separator sequence '###' occurs more than once, the string shall always be spliced at the last '###'.

Is there an operator like string.lastIndexOf("###"), like in C#?

This is how my parser looks like:

```
func parseTuple(from string: String) -> (String, Int)? {
    let parsedString = string.components(separatedBy: "###")
    if let tupleString = String(parsedString[0]), let tupleInt = Int(parsedString[1]) {
        return (tupleString, tupleInt)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: Connect###Four###Player###7 should be parsed to a string "Connect###Four###Player" and to an int 7. So no matter how many '###' there are, the function shall always split the last one and leave out the remaining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`range(of:...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1642786-range) method of `String` has a `.backwards` option
to find the last occurrence of a string.
Then `substring(to:)` and `substring(from:)` can be used with the
lower/upper bound of that range to extract the parts of the string
preceding/following the separator:

```
func parseTuple(from string: String) -> (String, Int)? {

    if let theRange = string.range(of: "###", options: .backwards),
        let i = Int(string.substring(from: theRange.upperBound)) {
        return (string.substring(to: theRange.lowerBound), i)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Example:

```
if let tuple = parseTuple(from: "Connect###Four###Player###7") {
    print(tuple)
    // ("Connect###Four###Player", 7)
}
```

---

**Swift 4 update:**

```
func parseTuple(from string: String) -> (String, Int)? {

    if let theRange = string.range(of: "###", options: .backwards),
        let i = Int(string[theRange.upperBound...]) {
        return (String(string[...theRange.lowerBound]), i)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Works liquidly :). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
let input = "Connect###Four###Player###7"

let seperator = "###"
// split components
var components = input.components(separatedBy: seperator)
// remove the last component ...
components = Array(components.dropLast())
// ... and re-join the remaining ones
let output = components.joined(separator: seperator)

print(output)
```

prints:

```
Connect###Four###Player
```