# How to get String with specific index - swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

For example i have String of `"version/ofswift/developer".` and i want print which starts from back side until the specific index like my specific index will be "/" then the answer should be "developer". What code snippet would do that, and being the most swift-like? I can't find any good practice. I hope you will help me to figure it out. Thank In Advance.

Comment: show us what have you tried? past your code

Comment: There is a function something like “separatedBy” but I can’t think what it is right now. Take a look at String docs for Swift.

Comment: @Pratik i have tried with subStrig method. But it is not like i am expected.

Comment: @Fogmeister yes, i will be checking with that.

Comment: That looks like a file path – in that case you should `URL` and `lastPathComponent`

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44883983/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Obviously what i am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String method `components(separatedBy:)` to produce an array and then get the last element using `last`

```
let string = "version/ofswift/developer"
let lastComponent = string.components(separatedBy: "/").last
```